Azure Data Factory Pipeline (imported from template) Fails in Acceptance Environment Due to NVARCHAR Length Issue
I have created a data pipeline in Azure Data Factory that reads data from a CSV file and loads it into a SQL database. The table/CSV has 369 columns. In the data flow, I have created a derived column activity between source and sink to enforce each column to its data type and length (for string columns). This was a significant amount of work to capture all 369 columns individually. The pipeline runs successfully in the development environment.
To move it to the acceptance environment, I exported the pipeline as a template and imported it into acceptance. However, when I run the pipeline in the acceptance environment, I get the following error:

Job failed due to reason: at Sink 'sink1': The given value of type NVARCHAR(21) from the data source cannot be converted to type nvarchar(20) of the specified target column D1001CRM_XYSQN.

In the derived column activity, I have enforced this as:

D1001CRM_XYSQN = subString(trim(D1001CRM_XYSQN), 1, 20)

This works in the DEV environment but doesn't in Acceptance. I suspect this might be the case with other columns as well. I do not want to spend hours manually enforcing each column once again in the acceptance environment.
Here are some additional details:

Both DEV and Acceptance environments should be identical in terms of data schema and data types.
The derived column expressions should have been exported and imported correctly with the pipeline template.

Questions:

Why is this issue occurring in the acceptance environment but not in the development environment? The derived column activity captures the correct length for each string type column, which worked very well in DEV? Am I missing something? In Dev, I imported the projection before running the derived column activity, but i dont import projection in acceptance, since i can see that all the columns are represented as needed.
Is there a more efficient way to ensure that all columns have the correct data type and length enforcement without having to redo the derived column activity for all 369 columns?

Screenshots:
Data flow:

Derivedd Column setting in Data flow:

Pipeline:


Do you want to apply this for all 369 columns  subString(trim(<column-name>), 1, 20) ?

not the same transformation, but depending upon the length of each column in the db.

Can you check sink in both environments? WHether they have same table structures, datatypes

Yes, they are both identical

Did you find any solution?

Nope. For now, I have set the pipeline to 'Continue on errors' and report as Success.
